# how to disable wildcard subdomain in ubuntu 18.04 for localhost

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

Hello and thank you your time, I have Xampp 7.2.29 installed and it's working fine

but i don't know why i can access any wildcard subdomain in localhost even i don't have created any in host file. 
when i go to
new.localhost it returns xampp dashboard and same goes for any subdomain *.localhost

host file

```
#127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#fe00::0 ip6-localnet
#ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
#ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Answer (score 0):

`.localhost` is a [Top-level domain - reserved domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain#Reserved_domains), so `foo.localhost` or `bar.localhost`, etc. always resolve to the same ip, 127.0.0.1, which in this case is used for Xampp.

Comment: but in windows you can't access sudomain until you create one in host file, And in this ubuntu i can't just disable the wildcards i really want to just disable the wildcard subdomains